# launchd simple recursive program to retrieve email with getmail

Tags: email, launchd, plist, macos

I adapted the following plist as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
      <key>Label</key>
      <string>com.bot.getmail</string>
      <key>Program</key>
      <string>/usr/local/bin/getmail</string>
      <key>ProgramArguments</key>
      <array>
         <string>/usr/local/bin/getmail</string>
         <string>--rcfile</string>
         <string>getmailrc</string>
      </array>
      <key>StartInterval</key>
      <integer>120</integer>
   </dict>
</plist>
```

and loaded it with

`sudo launchctl load -w Library/LaunchAgents/mail.plist`

But I get the following error in /var/log/system.log

`mac-home com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.bot.getmail[6182]): Service exited with abnormal code: 3`

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Dies it work if you attempt it manually?

Comment: Try directing errors (and probably regular output as well) to somewhere you can see them by adding the `StandardErrorPath` and `StandardOutPath` keys.